Animation Time Series of GOES Data Plots
currently stuck trying to animate a graph using data from the GOES CDAweb database. I just want it to draw the graph in time so I can eventually sync it with an audiofile of the same data.
Here is the code that plots the graphs - I just want to add in a GIF or MP4 in addition to the graphs this code outputs:
f,axs = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(8,8),dpi=200)

axs\[0\].set_title('27/04/2022')
axs\[0\].plot(dts,VDH\[:,0\],'b-')
axs\[0\].set_ylabel('B Field Strength VDH - V \[nT\]')
axs\[0\].set_xlim(dts\[576000\],dts\[-1\])
format_time_axis(axs\[0\])

axs\[1\].plot(dts, befilteredV)
axs\[1\].set_ylabel("V filtered (nT)")
axs\[1\].set_ylim(\[-4,4\])
axs\[1\].set_xlim(dts\[576000\],dts\[-1\])
format_time_axis(axs\[1\])

plt.show()

plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(8,4),dpi=200)
plt.title('27/04/2022')
cmap =  plt.get_cmap('jet')
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(befilteredV, fs,
noverlap = NFFT / 4,
nperseg=NFFT,
detrend='linear')
sg_db = 10 \* np.log10(Sxx)
plt.pcolormesh(t,f,sg_db, cmap=cmap, vmin=db_min, vmax=db_max)
plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal',label='Power \[dB\]')
plt.ylim(\[0, freqlim\])
plt.xlim(57600,86399)
plt.ylabel("Frequency (Hz)")
plt.xlabel("Time")
formatter = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(timeTicks)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.show()

I've tried this, and it runs, but nothing outputs:
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def animate(i):
    axs()
    ax.plot(x[:i], y[:i])
    ax.set_xlim([x0, tfinal]) 
    ax.set_ylim([1.1*np.min(y), 1.1*np.max(y)]) 
    

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames =  100, interval = 1, repeat = True, blit = False)

plt.show()

